# How do I find the positive value followed by two negative value in a column?

Tags: python, pandas

[![Here is my dataframe][1]][1]

I need to find the positive value in 'GDP_Change' that is followed by two negative value.

Comment: Add a sample case?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you can do it this way:

```
In [244]: df
Out[244]:
   GDP_Change
0           1
1         -12
2         -13
3         -14
4           5
5           5
6          -3
7          -4
8           6
9          -1

In [245]: df[(df.GDP_Change>=0) & (df.GDP_Change.shift(-1)<0) & (df.GDP_Change.shift(-2)<0)]
Out[245]:
   GDP_Change
0           1
5           5
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a NumPy based vectorized solution using `convolution` to catch a pattern -

```
In [503]: df
Out[503]: 
    GDP_Change
0     0.741415
1     0.058691
2    -0.270648
3     0.929434
4    -0.717600
5    -0.617052
6     1.365104
7     1.796394
8    -1.634185
9    -0.147893
10    0.215784
11   -1.228324
12    1.412208
13    0.660015
14    0.070062
15    0.613411
16   -0.595652
17   -1.849354
18   -1.542668
19    0.587222

In [504]: df.iloc[np.convolve(np.sign(df['GDP_Change']),[-1,-1,1],'valid')==3]
Out[504]: 
    GDP_Change
3     0.929434
7     1.796394
15    0.613411
```

Notice that the pattern used as the kernel for convolution is flipped : `[-1,-1,1]` as that's how [`convolution`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) works by sliding through the input data through the other direction. Then, we look for the maximum convolved summation for the match, which would be `3` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
x=[3,5,-7,5,10,-8,-9,3] 
index=0

for i in x[:-2]:
    if i > 0 and x[index+1] < 0 and x[index+2] < 0:
        print i
    index += 1
```